# How to get a random matrix with almost one number 1 in each row in R

Tags: r

I've done a random matrix of capture-recapture histories with numbers 1 and 0 through "for loop". I need that each time I generate the matrix it has almost one number 1 in each  row. But if I try with "while loop" there is always a row without one.

```
M = 10
oc=5
p = runif(oc, 1 , 1)
phi = runif(oc, 0.2, 0.2) 
hc.mat = matrix(0, M, oc)
z.mat = matrix(0, M, oc)

#For the occasion 1
z.mat[,1] = rbinom(M, 1, phi[1])
hc.mat[,1] = rbinom(M, 1, p[1]*z.mat[,1])

#For occasions >1
for (i in 2:oc) { 
  z.mat[,i] = rbinom(M, 1, phi[i])
  hc.mat[,i] = rbinom(M, 1, 1*z.mat[,i]) 
  j <- sum(hc.mat[1:length(M),])
  while (j >= 1) {
    break; print(hc.mat)
  } 
}
hc.mat
```

Comment: Can you give me some more contexts (e.g., what do rows and columns represent)?  There are many ways to force each row have at least a value "1", but how you should do this depends on your study.  By the way, It seems `hc.mat` and `z.mat` are identical.

Comment: my approach would be to make a random number matrix and then put 1s in random rows for each column

Comment: Hi, the number of columns represent OCCASIONS and each row represent tagged animals. The whole matrix must be generated randomly and it must be stop when each row has almost one number 1. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, the number of columns represent OCCASIONS and each row represent tagged animals. The whole matrix must be generated randomly and it depends of a probability .The matrix must be stop when each row has almost one number 1. Thanks!!